# How to recognize entities in text that is the output of optical character recognition (OCR)?

Tags: nlp, recurrent-neural-network, text-classification, named-entity-recognition, named-entity-extraction

I am trying to do multi-class classification with textual data. Problem I am facing that I have unstructured textual data. I'll explain the problem with an example.
consider this image for example:

[image: example data]

I want to extract and classify text information given in image. Problem is when I extract information OCR engine will give output something like this:

```
18
EURO 46
KEEP AWAY
FROM FIRE
MADE IN CHINA
2226249917581
7412501
DOROTHY
PERKINS
```

Now target classes here are:

```
18 -> size
EURO 46 -> price
KEEP AWAY FROM FIRE -> usage_instructions
MADE IN CHINA -> manufacturing_location
2226249917581 -> product_id
7412501 -> style_id
DOROTHY PERKINS -> brand_name
```

Problem I am facing is that input text is not separable, meaning "multiple lines can belong to same class" and there can be cases where "single line can have multiple classes".

So I don't know how I can split/merge lines before passing it to classification model.
 Is there any way using NLP I can split paragraph based on target class. In other words given input paragraph split it based on target labels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only consider the text, this is a Named Entity Recognition (NER) task.

What you can do is [**train** a Spacy model to NER for your particular problem](https://spacy.io/usage/training#section-ner).

Here is what you will need to do:

1. First gather a list of training text data
2. Label that data with corresponding entity types
3. Split the data into training set and testing set
4. Train a model with Spacy NER using training set
5. Score the model using the testing set
6. ...
7. Profit!

See [Spacy documentation on training specific NER models](https://spacy.io/usage/training#section-ner)

Good luck!

Comment: Any idea on the amount of training data required for a decent accuracy (>80%)?